# How to don't separate Sheet When SSRS report contain page break and export to excel?

Tags: reporting-services

i have a report in SSRS 2017 version 4.8.

i create 3 tab for show different information
and set tab 1 breaklocation is End, Disable is False.
and set tab 2 breaklocation is End, Disable is False.
and set tab 3 breaklocation is None, Disable is False.

Now, when i choose tab 1 and tab 2 and export to excel. it will separate tab 2 of two tab and final tab 2 is a blank page. look like below.

[image]

Expect Result, only show one tab1 and one tab2 when i choose tab 1, tab 2 and export to excel

[image]

Updated on :08/01/2021
Change breaks for each table to the Start instead of End with no breaks for Tab 1. it would be split one tab(sheet) for show title  eg .Title

Another tab is show Data(tab1)

[image: ![enter image description here]
[image]

Anybody can give advice ? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is due to the table creating a new tab at the END and no new tab 3 table.

Change your breaks for each table to the Start instead of End with no breaks for Tab 1.

This will only add the page breaks when the tab is created. If a table is disabled, the page break won't be created for it.

Comment: HI Hannover Fist, thank your support! it seems not work when i change breaks for each table to the Start instead of End with no breaks for Tab 1.Each tab will separate tab with blank page

Comment: @ericso - not sure what the issue is. We just changed the Break location so the data should be the same. Are you are using table 1 for just a title? I assume when you say **tab** you mean **table**. Usually you would just a an extra header row for the title or a text box abovce the table.

Comment: hi  Hannover Fist. i changed the break and export the excel of the tab is ok now, no extra tab appear, but when i export one tab eg.tab1 .There will be one more tab before the tab 1 page. extra tab is show the title only . another tab no title just data only.so difficult /3\